# CollabNet Subversion - Providing restricted user access to subfolders in a repository

Tags: svn, restrict

We need to provide restricted access to users at subfolder level within a repository such that the users can able to view only their folders and not the other ones. However we are unable to achieve it. Following are the access rules set up.

```
[Repo:/Folder1]
User1 = rw

[Repo:/Folder2]
User2 = rw
```

When the above rules are set, `User1` and `User2` are unable to access the repository `Repo` and "Forbidden Access to Repository" error is shown. To resolve this error we tried providing an additional `read` access at repository level as below.

```
[Repo:/]
User1 = r
User2 = r
```

This resolved the error however, `User1` was able to view all files under `Folder2` and `User2` was able to view files under `Folder1`. Our requirement is to provide `rw` access only to the concerned folders and hide the rest of the folders. `User1` should not know that `Folder2` exists under repository `Repo` and `User2` should not know that `Folder1` exists. Please guide on how this can be achieved.

Comment: You say that `User1` and `User2` are unable to access the repository. It makes sense that they aren't able to access the root of the repository because you haven't granted them permission to access the root. However, can `User1` access `/Folder1` and can `User2` access `/Folder2`? How are you testing "access"? Have you tried checking out a working copy of those paths with the respective user?

Comment: The [Path-Based Authorization chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) of the SVN book may be of help to you.

Comment: @RjOllos - Thanks for sharing the link. Using the info from the link, we have the resolved the issue of hiding the non-concerned folders.

Comment: I'm not sure you strictly need to grant access to the root of the repository in order to allow a user to access a subfolder. That's why I was asking how you are testing access. The [authenticated "magic token"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.authclass-tokens) would help with simplifying the scenario you describe though.

Comment: Unless providing access to the root, I am unable to provide access to the subfolders. During testing, I found that the both the users are able to checkout both the folders irrespective of the visibility of folders in repo-browser. I checked the "magic token" link but don't think it would work as desired as both users need to have access to specific folders within the repository and should not even have read access to the unwanted folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement has been handled as below thereby hiding the folders visible to the users.

```
[Repo:/]
User1 = rw
User2 = rw

[Repo:/Folder1]
User1 = rw
User2 =

[Repo:/Folder2]
User1 = 
User2 = rw
```

The access rules are going to grow if more sub-folders are added, however currently it is solving our issue as the number of sub-folders are less. Similarly creating appropriate user groups has helped in proper maintenance.